# How to convert UTM to Lat Long without removing it from a more complex dataframe?

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, utm

I have UTM coordinates in a data frame with 14 other columns.

I am using the code below to: 1. Pull the UTM (easting and northing) from a shape file into a separate data frame. 2. Convert it to lat/long using proj4. 3. Join it back to the original df using `innerjoin` and a column I created in both data frames based on the row name.

Is there a cleaner way to convert the coordinates, hopefully without moving the coordinate data into and out of the data frame?  proj4 seems to only work with two columns.  Here's what I'm currently looking at when I'm finished.

[image]

```
> higeo= readOGR(dsn=".", layer="ahupuaa") #Read in shape file
  OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
  Source: ".", layer: "ahupuaa"
  with 725 features
  It has 8 fields
> higeo@data$id = rownames(sf@data) #add row numbers as a column
> higeo.points = fortify(higeo, region="id") #pull point data from each   “region”
> higeo.df = inner_join(higeo.points, higeo@data, by="id") #join individual points back to data via id field
> higeo.df$rowid = rownames(higeo.df) #begin again, add “rowid”  this time.
> hicoords <- data.frame(x=higeo.df$lon, y=higeo.df$lat) #create xy values in new df, because proj4 only handles 2 columns
> proj4string <- "+proj=utm +zone=4 +north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"#define proj4string to contain constants
> hiconv <- project(hicoords, proj4string, inverse=TRUE)#converts to lat long
> hiconv.df$rowid = rownames(hiconv.df)# add rownames as column
> newhi.df <- inner_join(hiconv.df, higeo.df, by="rowid") #rejoin dfs by rowid
```

Comment: Are you using `fortify` because you want to use `ggplot2`?

Comment: I'm using `fortify` because I know some `ggplot2` and I thought it would do what I want, which was pull out the values of the actual points that make up the shape files and put them in a dataframe.  If I'm not using `ggplot2`.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: See my updated answer. I have a reproducible example at: https://gist.github.com/jsta/cbf16ae5f354b7c64cc158b5fac3073f

Comment: I'm getting an error from the `download.file`.  Otherwise, I think I understand what you're getting at.  I'll try to get it to work after manually downloading some shape files and let you know.    https://i.imgur.com/JamYooc.png

Answer (score 1):

Use `hiconv <- sp::spTransform(higeo, CRS(proj4string))` to project and
`as.data.frame(hiconv)` to view as a `data.frame`.

Also see:

- https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf